# ANOVA table help

Tags: anova

I need to find values for the starred values. I have been trying for some time but cannot figure out how to find them. I was able to find the Degrees of freedom, F and Significance of F. I have no idea where to even start. Please help.[image]

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Ok, i was able to find what mse and sse are by squaring standard error and then multiplying by the degrees of freedom. I am still at a loss for ssr and msr though. Please it would be appreciated if anyone can help as i am preparing for an exam on tuesday! :)

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. You find SSR by multiplying MSE and F. SSR=MSR.